# Unable to start mariadb service on WSL2 (Win10) Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 22.04, mariadb

I'm trying to run the **mariadb** service on **Ubuntu 22.04** on **WSL2** but with no success. The MariaDB service could not be started.

#### Environment:

- Microsoft Windows `[Version 10.0.19044.1645]`
- WSL2 with `Ubuntu-22.04`
- Kernel version: `5.10.102.1`

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04 from Microsoft Store
2. Run Ubuntu 22.04 from Menu Start
3. Execute `sudo apt update`
4. Execute `sudo apt upgrade`
5. Execute `exit`
6. Run `wsl --shutdown` from Powershell to restart WSL
7. Run Ubuntu 22.04 from Menu Start again
8. Execute `sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client`
9. Execute `sudo service mariadb start`

   **And here comes the problem:**

   ```
   * Starting MariaDB database server mariadbd       [fail]
   ```

#### The output from `sudo mysqld --verbose --user root` looks like this:

```
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1) starting as process 458 ...
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first data file './ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibdata1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibdata1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 100663296 bytes
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log file created, LSN=10329
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.7 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 3
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
2022-05-11 18:38:35 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Warning: Memory not freed: 280
```

#### The output from `sudo mysqld --verbose --user wzgf` looks like this:

```
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1) starting as process 496 ...
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The data file './ibdata1' must be writable
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The data file './ibdata1' must be writable
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-05-11 18:41:41 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

#### Additional remarks:

- Other services like Apache2 work fine
- On the same machine on WSL2 with previous Ubuntu (20.04) everything works fine

Comment: try `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/`. sometimes the mysql data doesn't get installed in the place where mariadb is looking for them, and this will install the tables in the correct place. possibly just `mysql_install_db` will be enough

Comment: I tried this idea a few hours ago but still with no success

Comment: @kanlukasz I just tried on WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm not able to reproduce.  Can you double-check `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell) to make sure that the instance didn't get set as WSL1 somehow?  I doubt it's the problem, but want to rule out the simple-stuff first.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I checked. This is v2 ```( Ubuntu-22.04  /  Stopped  /  2 )```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.6/+bug/1969160

Set innodb_use_native_aio=0 in 50-server.cnf. You may have to run:
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql

Comment: Thanks! Is there a special line to put the `innodb_use_native_aio=0` in 50-server.cnf. Also, `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql` doesn't work for me, I got the following message: `mysql.user table already exists! Run mysql_upgrade, not mysql_install_db`